# Determing the inverse in an abstract group of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S$ be a set and $G$ a subgroup of $S^S$. Further $1$ denotes the neutral element of the group. If $T = 1(S)$, then $f(S) = T$ for any $f \in G$ and $f|_T:T \to T$ is a bijection. If we consider the restrictions $$1|_{S\setminus T}: S\setminus T \to T \qquad f|_{S\setminus T}: S\setminus T \to T$$ Now I have to show, that $$f|_{S\setminus T} = f|_T \circ 1|_{S\setminus T}$$ and I have to state the inverse of $f$ in $G$.

**Thoughts.** Let $s \in S\setminus T$. Then $$f(s) = 1(f(s)) = f(1(s))$$ and $$f|_{S\setminus T} = f|_T \circ 1|_{S\setminus T}$$ simply holds. Is this correct?

For the inverse, I think I should split the domain $S$ into $T$ and $S\setminus T$. Since $f$ is bijective on $T$, the function $f^{-1}|_T$ is the inverse. However, I am not sure how to find the inverse on $S\setminus T$. Any ideas? It is obvious that $f|_{S\setminus T} = f|_T \circ 1|_{S\setminus T}$ has to be involved, but I do not really see how.